# How to start text after a subsection in book?

Tags: macros, sectioning, positioning

As in the title, I'm working in the `\documentclass{book}`. I have to start the text right after `\subsection` which should be also bolded. The trick is that I cannot use any packages. Can someone help me or recommend me any sources to learn it?

I also have to center each `\section` which should be numbered by `§` sign, again without any packages.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: _"I cannot use any packages"_ why? also what means: _"I have to start the text right after \subsection"_?

Comment: It is better to provide a sample of code.

Comment: " which should be also bolded" you mean text?

Comment: I meant text. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\centering \S{} }}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {-1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\section{Foo}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. 
\subsection{Foo}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. 

\end{document}
```

[image]